# REST API with Kotlin and Spring BootPost return empty objects

Tags: rest, spring-boot, kotlin

I'm new in Kotlin language and I try a simple RESTFUL API with Kotlin and Spring Boot. My query methods are not returning the expected result. I was hoping to receive this upon return of the requisition:

```
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "string 1",
        "color": "string 1"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "string 2",
        "color": "string 2"     
    }
]
```

But I receive this (HTTP status 200):

```
[
  {},
  {}
]
```

My data base have categories and my service and repository perform OK.This is the code of my controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/category")
class CategoryController (val categoryService: CategoryService) {

    @GetMapping
    fun findAll(): ResponseEntity<Any> {
        try {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(categoryService.findAll())
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            val msg = "Something went wrong: " + e.message
            return ResponseEntity(msg, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
        }

    }

}
```

What I'm doing wrong? I thank you for your help!

Comment: Are you sure that call to ``categoryService.findAll()`` returns valid results?

Comment: Yeap, thank you for your time, but i found the problem!

Answer (score 12):

I found the problem. My data class variables was private, i remove the private declaration and now the content is showed at the response body